# pyMC: implementing a joint distribution model

Tags: python, conditional-probability, joint-distribution, pymc

I'm attempting to model a multi-modal distribution that's affected by two separate distributions in pyMC and am having trouble implementing a joint or conditional distribution.

Suppose I have N data points $x_i \in (x_1,..,x_N)$. The samples are poisson distributed and then multiplied by $\alpha_i|B_i$, which takes on the form of one of two independent variables, either $C_{i_A}$ or $C_{i_B}$, which have values for each data point in $x$.

$$x_i \sim Poisson(\lambda = \phi) \cdot \alpha_i|B_i$$
$$C_{i_j} \in ([C_{1_A},C_{1_B}],..,[C_{N_A},C_{N_B}]) \quad where \quad j \in (A,B)$$
$$B_i \sim Binomial(p=\frac{C_{i_A}}{C_{i_A}+C_{i_B}})$$
$$\alpha_i|B_i \in (C_{1_{B_1}},..,C_{N_{B_N}})$$

i.e. for each $C_i$, select $C_{i_A}$ or $C_{i_B}$ based on a binomial coin toss, then multiply this by the values generated from each poisson distribution (apologies if the maths syntax isn't quite right).

We observe $x_1..x_N$ and $C_1..C_N$ directly, we just don't know which $A$ or $B$ of $C_i$ is "correct". I am trying to model the unknown $\phi$. My implementation so far in pyMC is like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm

N=100
#generate some observations of ca and cb
ca = (np.random.binomial(n=4, p=0.6, size=N)/2)+1
cb = (np.random.binomial(n=3, p=0.3, size=N)/2)+1

c = zip(map(float,ca),map(float,cb))

#set up pymc parameters
bi = pm.Container([pm.Binomial("bi_%d"%i, p=ci[0]/(ci[0]+ci[1]), size=1) for i,ci in enumerate(c)])    

phi = pm.Uniform('phi', lower=0, upper=200, size=N)
x_pois = pm.Poisson('x_pois', mu=phi, size=N)    

@pm.deterministic
def alpha(bi=bi):
    return [float(ci[a]) for ci,a in zip(c,bi)]
```

Now, how do I model the relationship between $\phi$ and $\alpha$? This requires some kind of conditional or joint distribution, where my observed data $x$ is sampled from the poisson distribution multiplied by the resulting array $\alpha|B$. Can I define a variable which is the product of two distributions, but takes the data x as observed input?